# Writing Socket Servers in PHP is it good idea?

Tags: php, c++, python, linux

Is it good idea to write Socket Servers using php??

here is how to article:
http://devzone.zend.com/article/1086

question:

What is different from writing socket servers in other languages like c, c++, python, ..?

how about security?

speed?

"Socket Servers normally run continuously as a service or a daemon."

php running continuesly?? will it work for a days, weeks, months?

what would be better way?

i need service that php application can connect to and send, receive data.

Comment: What are you doing?  I've written socket servers before in PHP.  They work well.  But don't expect any kind of concurancy (I used it as a master for a distributed system where children would check in from time to time).  It works, but don't expect to use it for production-quality usages.  So, what is your usecase?  What exactly are you trying to do that you don't know if PHP is right for?  But in general, you'll probably find C/C++ or Python is more suitable (If for nothing else than the support for threads).  Again, it depends on your needs (which you have said nothing of yet)

Comment: i need service that can receive data through sockets, on linux,

Comment: Simple saying i need api that connects to server with sockets

Comment: You really need to be more expressive! Repeating the word "sockets" doesn't help (:

Comment: @Eddsstudio, if you are familiar with C++ and Boost and if you simply need "api that connects to server with sockets", checkout Boost.Asio library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: I have made a socket server with PHP before. Not sure how it compares with other languages, but it definitely works. I run it on a VPS using a CLI only PHP build and no Apache. Works well. You have to set a shell ini script to make the daemon reload on bootup. Check out my Flash MMO Game to see it in action. Allows you to interact real time with other players (Demo only sofar). http://www.tenthtower.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not generally a good idea to write a (nontrivial) PHP program which executes for a long time. This is because its memory management is deficient in various ways, in particular, it fails to ever deallocate circularly referenced structures. Some other objects also leak. For example http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php allocates a function which can never be freed; call this inside a loop and you are eventually dead. In other languages it is possible to create function objects which are garbage collected.

However, if you are careful and test it properly, simple servers CAN be written in PHP, you just have to avoid doing any of the things which cause it to leak memory; most of them are easy to avoid in a small simple program.